How to compute Morton 3D BIGMIN?
I am looking for implementation of 3D Morton curve BIGMIN (computeBigMinFromMorton3D)
I am not interested for the interleaving the bits, naive algorithm is easy enough to implement (toMorton3D / fromMorton3D), also there are lots of resources about it.
Here is what I have in 2D. I removed some namespaces, not sure if it will compile as is.
namespace morton_curve_implementation_{
    constexpr uint64_t splitBits(uint64_t value){
        value &= 0xffff'ffff;

        value = (value ^ (value << 16)) & 0x0000'ffff'0000'ffff;
        value = (value ^ (value <<  8)) & 0x00ff'00ff'00ff'00ff;
        value = (value ^ (value <<  4)) & 0x0f0f'0f0f'0f0f'0f0f;
        value = (value ^ (value <<  2)) & 0x3333'3333'3333'3333;
        value = (value ^ (value <<  1)) & 0x5555'5555'5555'5555;

        return value;
    }

    constexpr uint64_t combineBits(uint64_t value){
        value &= 0x5555'5555'5555'5555;

        value = (value ^ (value >>  1)) & 0x3333'3333'3333'3333;
        value = (value ^ (value >>  2)) & 0x0f0f'0f0f'0f0f'0f0f;
        value = (value ^ (value >>  4)) & 0x00ff'00ff'00ff'00ff;
        value = (value ^ (value >>  8)) & 0x0000'ffff'0000'ffff;
        value = (value ^ (value >> 16)) & 0x0000'0000'ffff'ffff;

        return value;
    }
} // namespace morton_curve_implementation_

constexpr uint64_t toMorton2D(uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
    using namespace morton_curve_implementation_;

    return  (splitBits(x) << 1) |
        (splitBits(y) << 0);
}

constexpr auto fromMorton2D(uint64_t z){
    using namespace morton_curve_implementation_;

    auto combineBits32 = [](uint64_t value){
        return static_cast<uint32_t>(
            combineBits(value)
        );
    };

    struct Result{
        uint32_t x;
        uint32_t y;
    };

    return Result{
        combineBits32(z >> 1),
        combineBits32(z >> 0)
    };
}

uint64_t computeBigMinFromMorton2D(uint64_t z_current, uint64_t z_min, uint64_t z_max);

Here is bigmin:
namespace morton_curve_implementation_{
    namespace{
        constexpr uint64_t loadBits(uint64_t bit_pattern, uint64_t const bit_position, uint64_t const value, uint64_t const dim){
            // dim = 0 for x; dim = 1 for y

            uint64_t wipe_mask = ~(splitBits(0xffff'ffff >> (32u - (bit_position / 2u + 1u))) << dim);
            bit_pattern = splitBits(bit_pattern) << dim;
            return (value & wipe_mask) | bit_pattern;
        }

        constexpr auto combine3Bools(bool a, bool b, bool c){
            uint8_t result = 0;

            result |= a ? 0b0100 : 0b0000;
            result |= b ? 0b0010 : 0b0000;
            result |= c ? 0b0001 : 0b0000;

            return result;
        }
    } // anonymous namespace
} // namespace morton_curve_implementation_



uint64_t computeBigMinFromMorton2D(uint64_t const xd, uint64_t z_min, uint64_t z_max){
    using namespace morton_curve_implementation_;

    uint64_t bigmin = 0u;
    uint64_t mask = 0x8000'0000'0000'0000;
    uint32_t bit_position = 63u;

    do{
        auto const dim = bit_position % 2u;
        auto const bit_mask = 0x1 << (bit_position / 2u);

        auto const xd_bit    = xd    & mask;
        auto const z_min_bit = z_min & mask;
        auto const z_max_bit = z_max & mask;

        auto const magic = combine3Bools(xd_bit, z_min_bit, z_max_bit);

        switch(magic){
        case 0b0001:
            bigmin = loadBits(bit_mask - 0, bit_position, z_min, dim);
            z_max  = loadBits(bit_mask - 1, bit_position, z_max, dim);
            break;
        case 0b0010:
        case 0b0110:
            // not possible because min <= max
            return std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
        case 0b0011:
            bigmin = z_min;
            return bigmin;
        case 0b0100:
            return bigmin;
        case 0b0101:
            z_min = loadBits(bit_mask, bit_position, z_min, dim);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        --bit_position;

        mask >>= 1;
    }while(mask);

    return bigmin;
}

Also I have this class:
    struct MortonRectangle{
        uint32_t x1;
        uint32_t x2;
        uint32_t y1;
        uint32_t y2;

        uint64_t z_min = morton_curve::toMorton2D(x1, y1);
        uint64_t z_max = morton_curve::toMorton2D(x2, y2);

        constexpr MortonRectangle(uint32_t x1, uint32_t x2, uint32_t y1, uint32_t y2) :
                x1(x1), x2(x2),
                y1(y1), y2(y2){}

        constexpr bool inside(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) const{
            return x >= x1 && x <= x2 && y >= y1 && y <= y2;
        }

        auto bigmin(uint64_t z) const{
            return computeBigMinFromMorton2D(z, z_min, z_max);
        }
    };

